# Adding specific td to a specific row in a table with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Considering the following code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
      <td>IamaTextFieldBox</td>
      <td class="im-label-required">Label required</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
      <td>IamaTextFieldBox2</td>
      <td class="im-label-required">Label required2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
      <td>IamaTextFieldBox3</td>
      <td class="im-label-required">Label required3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

The following script allows to create a new `<tr class='tr00'>` above each `<tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">` and place the `<td class="im-label-required">` in the newly created `<tr>`.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr.wsui-table-row-odd").parent().prepend("<tr class='tr00'>");
  $(".tr00").append($("td.im-label-required"));
});
```

Problem is it's placing all 3 `<td class="im-label-required">` in each of the 3 newly created `<tr class='tr00'>`.

I would need the script to place solely the related `<td class="im-label-required">` in its related `<tr class='tr00'>` like so:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="tr00">
      <td class="im-label-required">Label required</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
      <td>IamaTextFieldBox</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr00">
      <td class="im-label-required">Label required2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
      <td>IamaTextFieldBox2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr00">
      <td class="im-label-required">Label required3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
      <td>IamaTextFieldBox3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

It should display:

```
Label required
IamaTextFieldBox
Label required2
IamaTextFieldBox2
Label required3
IamaTextFieldBox3
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure it's `IamaTextFieldBox`? Because the HTML above has `IamaTextFieldBo2`, `IamaTextFieldBox3` etc... See my updated answer.

Comment: @zer00ne Oh yes I edited it wrong. Thanks for the head's up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `prepend` you can use `insertBefore`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("<tr class='tr00'></tr>").insertBefore("tr.wsui-table-row-odd");
});
```

for detail reference you can check [click here](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wsui-table-row-odd').each(function(index,el){
  var newLabel = "<tr class='tr00'><td colspan='2'>" + $(this).find('.im-label-required').html() + "</td></tr>";
  $(newLabel).insertBefore(el);
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="2">
<tbody>
 <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
   <td>IamaTextFieldBox</td>
   <td class="im-label-required">Label required</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
   <td>IamaTextFieldBox2</td>
   <td class="im-label-required">Label required2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
   <td>IamaTextFieldBox3</td>
   <td class="im-label-required">Label required3</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**or if you want to move label: **

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wsui-table-row-odd').each(function(index,el){
 // var newLabel = "<tr class='tr00'><td>" + $(this).find('.im-label-required').html() + "</td></tr>";
  $(el).find('.im-label-required').insertBefore(el);
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="2" cellpadding="2">
<tbody>
 <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
   <td>IamaTextFieldBox</td>
   <td class="im-label-required">Label required</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
   <td>IamaTextFieldBox2</td>
   <td class="im-label-required">Label required2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="wsui-table-row-odd">
   <td>IamaTextFieldBox3</td>
   <td class="im-label-required">Label required3</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Super User Thanks it does the trick indeed in regards of the row creation (thanks for the doc) but not the label. $(".tr00").append($("td.im-label-required")); place all 3 found <td class="im-label-required"> in each of the 3 newly created rows. It duplicates them 3x. That is my issue, I would need to not duplicate them. I'd just need "label required1" in the first newly created <tr>, "label required2" in the second newly created <tr> ect..

Comment: @Super User This is it thanks ! :) I've added remove to remove the old `<td>`